# MMCX Bluetooth cable supporting current HighRes audio codecs

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, cable, earphones, bluetooth-5

I am searching for a **long lasting** Bluetooth "cable" which:

- battery lasts at least 8 hours (assume a ~36 ohm in-ear headphone),
- supports for current audio codecs like LDAC, aptX, ...,
- high quality headphone amplifier and,
- bonus, does support Bluetooth Low energy (BLE).

There is for example the [RMCE-BT2](https://www.shure.com/en-US/products/accessories/rmce-bt2). I wonder if there are better and cheaper products than this one.

[image]
<sub>(source: [rackcdn.com](https://522bb370f5443d4fe5b9-f62de27af599bb6703e11b472beadbcc.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/product/zoomable_image/10932/max_desktop_bt2-main-b.jpg))</sub>